# Can not remove arrow heads in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I added arrow heads in Inkscape through `Fill and Stroke editor`. Now I can not delete them.

Tried to find the option in the drop-down list which I used for the arrows addition, with no result.

[image]

Here is me trying to do that:
[image]

Comment: Did you do 'Stroke to path' on the objects, or maybe group them? The screenshot doesn't show what object type it is.
To help, we'd need a screenshot with the node tool active, the object selected, and the status line visible - or the SVG file itself.

Theoretically, a click on the empty field should be working, if the selected object is an object that has markers on it.

Comment: Just to be sure: your cursor in the screenshot hovers over an 'empty' field in the list of markers. This is what would need to be selected to remove a marker.

Comment: @Moini, how would you like me to send you the `.svg` file?

Comment: From the gif, it looks like you're just selecting the wrong arrow from the list - and it looks as if that empty arrow has no preview. Are there other empty fields in the list?

You can share svg files via dropbox, google drive, framadrop, imgh.us, or many other file hosters. You can remove everything that isn't needed to answer the question from the file.

Additionally, if you know how to find it, please also share the 'markers.svg' file from your Inkscape installation. Maybe it's incomplete or broken.

Comment: @Moini, [here](https://framadrop.org/r/MJoJBOwu_J#d4VFW8wYoATHa45uv4I5vKiBNLS46hpMxQprdhlkqsM=) it is.

Comment: Thank you, it's actually very easy - sorry it took so long to solve... (see below).

Comment: I believe this (along with other similar problems) is a bug and I have opened an issue on the Inkscape GitLab. https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/issues/1409

Answer (score 2):

I thought one had to select the empty field, but it turns out the preview for 'no marker' is a line with no marker. The empty fields are just the ones where the preview fails for some reason.

This is how it would look with no markers applied:

[image: no markers applied]

Comment: could not find the line that you describe